# multiple testng data providers

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

I have a data provider that has to do a db query on a status (status is int), and return a value (basically an employee matching this status).

I need to test for several (8 or 9) statii.

Now my data provider can have a loop through all the statii and do a query and return a list of users.  This will work, but will be only one test so I would have to pass or skip then entire test (I want to skip the test if I cannot find an employee matching that status).

On the other hand I can make 8  or so data providers, all performing exactly the same function with a different status, and write 8 tests but that seems like a waste.

I would like to do something like this.  I know this is not valid but is there a way do to this?

```
for ( i = 1; i < 8; i++ ) {
   @Test(dataProvider = "getTest" parameter = i
   public void myTest(){...}
}


@DataProvider
    public Object[][] getTest(int i) throws Exception {
       query("select * from table where status = i");
       if (notFound) skiptest;
    }
```

This is "pseudocode" I know but I would like to be able to do its functional equivalent.  Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the concept of data provider.

You can do this

```
@DataProvider(name="dataprv")
public Object[][] getTest() throws Exception {
   Object[][] data = new Object[1][any size. in your case it's i]
   query("select * from table where status = i");
   //pass the result of query to data[][]
   return data;
}
```

now in your test you can

```
@Test(DataProvider="dataprv")
public void testMethod(String status) {
    //status would be the data from the data provider.
    // your test will automatically iterate for every status from the dataprovider which in turn gets the data from database
}
```

Comment: Ours is a little confusing because they have added a lot of functionality so we don't return Object[][] but rather put data into a list which calls one of their methods which calls more methods to create the objects.  But I will try to analyze how they do it to see if I can figure out how to do it in the above.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of data you have. At the end you only have to return `Object[][]` or `Iterator`. Only then DataProvider will accept.